# What is the impact of passing method parameters to a function

Tags: java

What is the impact of passing method parameters to a function from the ability to process a certain method faster.

If a certain method needs locale as input.
You would declare this as `foo(Locale locale)` does `foo(User user) { Locale locale = user.getLocale(); }` necessarily slower than the previous one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need the user for some other reason in the same method, it would be pretty pointless to pass in a separate locale - and indeed it could lead to inconsistent results, if you passed in a *different* locale from the one for the user. This is assuming that `getLocale` is a simple property backed by a field, of course.

I would definitely write the simplest, most logical code first... micro-optimizations like this rarely make a difference in terms of performance, but *often* lead to code which is harder to understand. Only micro-optimize when you've shown that the given section of code is relevant, and only keep that optimization when you've shown that it achieves an improvement.

Give your method the information it needs, in the most straightforward way possible. If it needs the user, give it the user. If it only needs the locale, give it just the locale. If it needs the user *and* the locale, but the locale is associated with the user, then just give it the user and derive the locale appropriately.

(In the interests of balance, I should probably point to Joe Duffy's recent blog post [in favour of optimization](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/09/06/ThePrematureOptimizationIsEvilMyth.aspx). I disagree with the gist of that post, but it's still worth reading.)

Comment: Agreed 100%, clear logic and readability should be the first thing to consider when writing Java. If you need optimizations at this level, you're doing it wrong anyway (by using Java).

Answer (score 2):

```
foo(Locale locale)
```

Is definitely going to be faster than:

```
foo(User user)
{
    Locale locale = user.getLocale();
}
```

Because the later involves an extra method call. That doesn't necessarily mean that the program, as a whole, is going to be any slower because the locale has to come from somewhere so I'm guessing the calling code would then look like:

```
Locale locale = user.getLocale();
this.foo(locale);
```

Which results in the same exact method calls.

Comment: err... that should be "faster than" :-)

Comment: @Aaron - Doh! Yeah. Fixed it. Still early in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Run the actual production code in loop several million times and measure how fast it is. Do that **only** if the performance is not good enough.

Premature optimization is the source of a lot of evil. Don't do it.

Comment: Why would you do this?  Why not do A/B testing, which will provide *real* results, not *synthetic* ones?

Comment: It's my way of saying: "Just don't".